# Copy data to master workbook from another open workbook without specifying FileName

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

is there a way where I can copy and paste data from any open workbook without using `Workbooks.Open("FileName")` ? I want to be able to copy the same set of data from a workbook, close it, and when I open another workbook, the macro would know that I am copying from the second workbook.

For example:
**Code 1: Copying from first data source**

```
Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\HONL120\Desktop\Sept HC Reports\HR Headcount Report 2018 Australia SEPTEMBER.XLSX")
```

**Code 2: Copying from second data source**

```
    Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\HONL120\Desktop\Sept HC Reports\18 09 Malaysia HR Headcount Report 2018 (Sept).xlsx")
```

From the example above, I would like to avoid this and let the macro know that when I open the second data source, I am pulling data from it, without having to type out the filename over again.

Is there a way to achieve this? I hope my explanation is clear and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could loop through the open workbooks, and use an **If Statement** to ignore the ones you don't want to include:

```
Dim wb As Workbook

For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    If wb.Name <> "PERSONAL.XLSB" And wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then
        Rem: Do what you need to do with the other workbook
    End If
Next wb
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i didn't quite get what your goal is, but I suppose you can set a macro in your **excel template file** (please google on where it is locate, as it depends on your version), with the code **activeworkbook**.range(xxx).copy.

In this case whenever you open a new workbook you want to copy, run this macro in that excel (you can even set the macro to the quick access bar for easier access)

Hope this help.